# How to export cube animated with boonlean modifier to .glft?

Tags: animation, modifiers, export, gltf

blender 3.4.1

Is it possible to export this animated cube? I used the Boolean Modifier for the animation. The target format is .glb
[image]
It looks simple but I have tried different variations of these actions:
bake animation
export to .abc
import .abc and export .mdd
import .mdd and export .glb
and .fbx

No success so far...

.blend file:
https://storage.fleek.zone/54c212c3-61ec-458b-aff6-d56851b32e8e-bucket/clear.blend

thanks

Error when exporting .mdd----
**Exception: Error, number of verts has changed during animation, cannot export**

Comment: Unfortunately that's not going to work. Animating a Boolean produces different meshes at different points in the animation, so traditional object export can't support it.

Answer (score -1):

While the mdd workflow won't work with a boolean, it will work with a shrink-wrap modifier since the geometry is projected to the target and so it is preserved.

When using the shrink wrap modifier use project mode and use a vertex group for the surface you want to follow your target.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures